# Memory allocation fails with NO std::bad_alloc

Tags: memory-management, crash, c++17, bad-alloc

Consider these two cases where `II` and `JJ` are big enough.

```
// std::bad_alloc
new int[II*JJ];
```

and

```
// CRASH!
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < II; ++ii)
  new int[JJ];
```

So the first one throws `std::bad_alloc` while the second crashes! Was quite unexpected for me.

Tested on `gcc-7.2.0`. Is this a BUG?

Comment: Remember that the memory allocated needs to be contiguous. Allocating one large chunk of memory will fail immediately if none is available. Allocating multiple smaller regions will lead to fragmentation and a very different use-case.

Comment: Also note that this is more system-dependent than compiler-dependent. And you don't mention the operating system or its version.